# [Python3]RegEx to match multiple strings

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to match multiple stings, which also includes an optional capture group.

My RegEx:

```
(\[[A-Za-z]*\])(.*) - (.*)(.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}.)?(\[.*\])
```

Strings:

```
[Test]Kyubiikitsune - Company Of Wolves[20.06.96][Hi-Res]
[TEst]_ANother - Company Of 2[Hi-Res]
[Yes]coOl__ - some text_[20.06.96][Hi-Res]
```

How can I match all of these and optimize my RegEx? I'm still new to this.

Comment: Well, your pattern works. You may use lazy dot instead of a greedy one, but does that really matter? I'd use [`(\[[A-Za-z]*\])(.*?) - (.*?)(\[[0-9]{2}(?:\.[0-9]{2}){2}])?(\[[^][]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/hO0yF6/1), but without more input data, it is as good as yours.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For some reason your's works, but mine didn't. Is there a way to exclude the brackets around the date?

Comment: Yes, [`(\[[A-Za-z]*\])(.*?) - (.*?)(?:\[([0-9]{2}(?:\.[0-9]{2}){2})?])?(\[[^][]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/hO0yF6/2). Why doesn't yours work? Please post the code. (BTW, here is [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK2uR8/1)).

Comment: If you want your question answered, please share your code to repro the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I asume [this](https://regex101.com/r/dWHJWs/1) is what you want:
`r"\[(.*?)\](.*?)\s*-\s*(.*?)(?:\[(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\])?\[(.*?)\]"g`

Answer (score 0):

Consider approaching this with `pandas` as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a Series object containing the strings to be searched
s = pd.Series([
    '[Test]Kyubiikitsune - Company Of Wolves[20.06.96][Hi-Res]',
    '[TEst]_ANother - Company Of 2[Hi-Res]',
    '[Yes]coOl__ - some text_[20.06.96][Hi-Res]'
])

# use pandas' StringMethods to peform regex extraction; a DataFrame object is returned because your regex contains more than one capture group
s.str.extract('(\[[A-Za-z]*\])(.*) - (.*)(.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}.)?(\[.*\])', expand=True)

# returns the following
        0              1                            2    3         4
0  [Test]  Kyubiikitsune  Company Of Wolves[20.06.96]  NaN  [Hi-Res]
1  [TEst]       _ANother                 Company Of 2  NaN  [Hi-Res]
2   [Yes]         coOl__         some text_[20.06.96]  NaN  [Hi-Res]
```